# Get free disk space in percentage for multiple nodes using Grafana

Tags: metrics, grafana, collectd

I use Grafana (v2.1.3) for metrics visualization.
Metrics comes from Graphite collected by collectd. The target graph is to display **free** disk space in **percents** for **multiple** nodes, e.g. lets say folder is /data, so metric which represents free space in bytes is:

```
collectd.$node.df-data.df_complex-free
```

The metrics which represent total space is sum of:

```
collectd.$node.df-data.*
```

So, I have following config:

```
Series A: collectd.$node.df-data.df_complex-free (Invisible)
Series B: collectd.$node.df-data.* (Invisible)
Series C: alias(asPercent(#A, sumSeries(#B)), 'Free space')
```

Here $node is a variable which is selected from drop-down list (All, node1, node2, node3, etc.). It works as expected when one specific node is selected, but wrong one **All** option is selected, (e.g. if percentage per node is ~ 95%, then when All is selected 24% is displayed).

Another option (would be probably more preferable:

```
Series A: collectd.$node.df-data.df_complex-free
Series B: groupByNode(collectd.$node.df-data.*, 1, 'sum')
Series C: scale(divideSeries(#A, #B), 100)
```

Again for single node it's fine, but once "All nodes" option is selected, then following error is displayed:

*divideSeries second argument must reference exactly 1 series*

Any ideas? I believe there should be simple solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you're using collectd and the df plugin you can just enable the `ValuesPercentage` parameter in your `/etc/collectd.conf.d/df.conf`, then you'll be able to query `collectd.$node.df-data.percent_bytes-free`

https://collectd.org/wiki/index.php/Plugin:DF

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This simple config solves all percentage related issues.